# Correct way to have the same method defined differently between instances

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I'm trying to create a class in Python whose methods are defined differently (under the same name) between various instances. The different definitions could be based on the input to the class when creating an instance.

For example:

```
Class A:
     def __init__(self, a):
         ...

     def foo(self):
         ...

a1 = A(input1)
a2 = A(input2)
a1.foo()
a2.foo()
```

I would want `foo()` to be defined differently for these two instances. I can code this logic into the `foo` method but would like to know if there's a cleaner or more Pythonic way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this questionable technique?

Comment: Your example does not help in any way.

Comment: I have an object rendering method which works quite differently between various objects (instances). Instead of making a complex method that checks the instance and applies the specific rendering logic, I was curious if that can be done by multiple definitions of the same method based on the instance itself.

Comment: If the code for each instance is different, it may make sense to pass it as a callback when you create the instance. `A(a, some_function)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would want foo() to be defined differently for these two instances

You really don't want that. I can't start imagining the debugging nightmare this will cause.

If `a1.foo` is different than `a2.foo` it means `a1` and `a2` should not be instances of the same class

Use subclasses and implement `foo` in each class as appropriate:

```
Class Common:
    # common stuff
    ...

Class A1(Common):
    def foo(self):
        print('a1.foo')

Class A2(Common):
    def foo(self):
        print('a2.foo')

a1 = A1()
a2 = A2()
a1.foo()
# 'a1.foo'
a2.foo()
# 'a2.foo'
```

Comment: Separating it to subclasses is slightly messy in my case but seems like the correct solution. Note taken, thank you.

Comment: @bdemin it is not messy at all, especially when compared to other alternatives.

Comment: This is a good solution, and can probably do exactly what you want if you combine it with a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) method. You pass in `input1` or `input2` to `Common.__init__()` and it will return either an A1 or A2 object based on this input. You can then use them as if they are the same class as they have the same interfaces.

Comment: That's a great solution for my issue. Thank you @mattrea6 !

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** do that. But you can always add custom attributes to objects on-the-fly.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

a1 = A()
a2 = A()

def foo1():
    # you can't use self.x
    print("a1")

a1.foo = foo1
a2.foo = lambda : print("a2")

a1.foo() # a1
a2.foo() # a2
```

This is not a good practice though, use it at your own risk.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you don't have access to instance attributes (because there is no implicit `self` parameter).

Comment: Just because you *can* do a thing doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: Didn't know I can add methods to an instance on-the-fly. Thank you.

Comment: And how will you access instance attributes from the lambda?